# Embedding publisher policy into assembly

Tags: .net, assemblies, shared, policy, publisher

I'm developing a shared assembly, version 2.0.0.0.
For future compatibility, I'd like to bind all the 2.0.x.x versions to the latest version installed. To do so I need a publisher policy file. 
Is there a way to embed the publisher policy directly in the "code" assembly instead of having to install two different assemblies?

I.e. my assembly will be ALWAYS in the GAC, since it is not allowed to run separated from the application it wraps.

Thank you.
QbProg

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such solution. Publisher policy assemblies are separate. (This lets the user/admin decide whether they want to install them or not.) The kicker is the part of the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dz32563a.aspx) that says that the assembly name must follow the format `policy.majorNumber.minorNumber.mainAssemblyName.dll`.

Comment: I'm not sure I really accept the reasoning for having it this way though; it seems more convenient to have it all in the same place, and they could still allow the sysadmin to override it with config file settings if required.